# AWSMobileHubHelper add User pool as AWSIdentityProvider, how to handle `func login(completionHandler: (AnyObject, NSError) -> Void)`?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I want to add AWS User pool as a AWSIdentityProvider to my iOS Application,

But there is little guide for the AWSMobileHubHelper.

So I've try it by my self.

In my `LoginViewController` I treat AWS User pool as other provider like this:

```
final
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    var passwordAuthenticationCompletion: AWSTaskCompletionSource!
    var completionHandler: ((AnyObject, NSError) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance().setPermissions(["public_profile"]);
        AWSGoogleSignInProvider.sharedInstance().setScopes(["profile", "openid"])
        AWSGoogleSignInProvider.sharedInstance().setViewControllerForGoogleSignIn(self)
    }


    @IBAction private func facebookLogin() {
        handleLogin(signInProvider: AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance())
    }

    @IBAction private func googleLogin() {
        handleLogin(signInProvider: AWSGoogleSignInProvider.sharedInstance())
    }

    @IBAction private func myLogin() {
        handleLogin(signInProvider: LoginProvider.sharedInstance())
    }

    private func handleLogin(signInProvider signInProvider: AWSSignInProvider) {
        title = "Loging ..."

        AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().loginWithSignInProvider(signInProvider) { (result, error) in
            switch error {
            case let error? where error.domain != "success":
                print("Login failed.")

            default:
                print("Login succeed.") 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `LoginProvider` code:

```
final
class LoginProvider: NSObject {

    static func sharedInstance() -> LoginProvider {
        return _sharedInstance
    }

    static private let _sharedInstance = LoginProvider()

    lazy var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool = {
        let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)
        let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "clientId", clientSecret: "clientSecret", poolId: "poolId")
        AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration(serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: "UserPool")
        let result = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
        result.delegate = self
        return result
    }()
}

extension LoginProvider: AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate {

    func startPasswordAuthentication() -> AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {
        return loginViewController
    }

    func startMultiFactorAuthentication() -> AWSCognitoIdentityMultiFactorAuthentication {
        fatalError("Identity MultiFactor Authentication Not Supportted!")
    }

    private var loginViewController: LoginViewController {
        return LoginViewController.sharedInstance
    }
}

extension LoginProvider: AWSIdentityProvider {

    var identityProviderName: String {
        return pool.identityProviderName
    }

    func token() -> AWSTask {
        return pool.token()
    }
}

extension LoginProvider: AWSSignInProvider {

    var loggedIn: Bool {
        @objc(isLoggedIn) get {
            return currentUser?.signedIn ?? false
        }
    }

    var imageURL: NSURL? {
        return nil
    }

    var userName: String? {
        return currentUser?.username
    }

    func login(completionHandler: (AnyObject, NSError) -> Void) {
        loginViewController.completionHandler = completionHandler
        loginViewController.doLogin()
    }

    func logout() {
        currentUser?.signOut()
    }

    func reloadSession() {
        currentUser?.getSession()
    }

    func interceptApplication(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func interceptApplication(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    private var currentUser: AWSCognitoIdentityUser? {
        return pool.currentUser()
    }

}
```

I've extended my `LoginViewController` to support the process:

```
extension LoginViewController: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {

    func doLogin() {            
        pool.getUser(usernameTextField.text!).getSession(usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, validationData: nil).continueWithBlock { task -> AnyObject? in
            print("pool.getUser().getSession")
            print("task.result:", task.result)
            print("task.error:", task.error)

            if let session = task.result as? AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession {
                print("session.idToken:", session.idToken?.tokenString)
                print("session.accessToken:", session.accessToken?.tokenString)
                print("session.refreshToken:", session.refreshToken?.tokenString)
                print("session.expirationTime:", session.expirationTime)

            }

            switch (task.result, task.error) {
            case let (_, error?):
                    self.completionHandler?("", error)
                    self.completionHandler = nil
            case let (result?, _):
                    self.completionHandler?(result, NSError(domain: "success", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
                    self.completionHandler = nil
            default: break
            }
            return nil
        }

    }

    func getPasswordAuthenticationDetails(authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource) {
        self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
    }

    func didCompletePasswordAuthenticationStepWithError(error: NSError?) {
        switch error {
        case let error?:
            Queue.Main.execute {
                self.completionHandler?("", error)
                self.completionHandler = nil
            }
        default: break
        }

    }

    private var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool! {
        return LoginProvider.sharedInstance().pool
    }
}

extension LoginViewController {

    @nonobjc static let navigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController

    static var sharedInstance: LoginViewController {
        return navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! LoginViewController
    }
}
```

Now I can login to my user pool, but I can't integrate it with federated id pool, It think I've give a wrong result when use `completionHandler`.

In `LoginViewController`'s `func doLogin()` , when i get the `getSession()`'s result which is `AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession`, How can I convert it to other result that `completionHandler` needed?

Comment: Hi, currently the Mobile Hub Helper Framework does not support login with User Pools. You will have to an integration directly with Cognito. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use Cognito, Thanks.

Comment: I'm having similar issues. I can get through fine, and even get a unique id from cognito, but I don't get any roles.. I think we need an example from Amazon as to how we intergate AWS Cognito User Pools / Federated Identities and Mobile Hub Helper

Comment: The best approach is that mobile hub integrate all these stuff then generate working code for us, but it's just a feature request for now. After all i found the source code of  AWSMobileHubHelper https://github.com/aws/aws-mobilehub-helper-ios  , it provides useful information for me, I've improved my solution but there is still some problem.